# How to go to anchor after page is posted to the server

Tags: php

I want to add something like '#coupon' to my page's url. can any one help me?

`http://www.myhost.com/design-brief.php#coupon`

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['TryCoupon'])) 
    {
        // I need something here
        // I dont want to use Location to direct as I am on the same page and want to preserve field values
    } 
?>
```

I have a anchor on my page and I want the user to go to that when user submits the form.

```
<td id="coupon"></td>
```

Comment: Did you try using header("Location: http://www.myhost.com/wordpress/design-brief.php#coupon"); ? Should work just fine.

Comment: Otherwise, try using a plain old link. <a href='#coupon'>Hello!</a>

Comment: did you integrated jQuery and after submit it is comming on the given url?

Comment: try: <a href="http://www.myhost.com/wordpress/design-brief.php?coupon' "><\a>

Comment: @Johny You may want to rethink that link layout.

Comment: So what prevents you from adding something like '#coupon' to your page's url?

Comment: I have a anchor on my page and I want the user to go to that when user submits the form.

Comment: Please read the description above. I have updated it

Answer (score 2):

Change the action of the form to include the anchor:

```
<form method="post" action="/some/index.php#coupon">
```

this will post to /some/index.php and when the page is displayed, it will goto the anchor too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['TryCoupon'])) 
{
  header("Location:place/your/url/here");
}
?>
```